# Local GAE Datastore is empty after restart on OSX

Tags: google-app-engine, go, polymer

I'm building a Google App Engine application with a Go backend + Polymer frontend. As a result, I'm using a dispatch.yaml file to serve both at the same time.

The problem I'm facing is that the datastore is empty when I restart my computer. I've tested this on both OSX 10.9.5 and 10.10.4. Both exhibit the same response upon a system reboot. Windows 7, however, seems to hold on to the data.

The documentation suggests that data should persist, since I'm not explicitly calling a clear. It's not. I've tried to set the datastore location myself using this:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=~/go_apps/data ~/go_apps/my_app
```

I'm receiving this error:

```
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.AppConfigNotFoundError: "/Users/anthony/go_apps/my_app is a directory but does not contain app.yaml or app.yml
```

Obviously, since I'm using a dispatch.yaml file, it wouldn't. So, since the `backend`, which handles the data, does have an `app.yaml` file, I try to set it there. I use this command:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=~/go_apps/data ~/go_apps/my_app/backend
```

That doesn't seem to work either, as I get this error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

Okay? Well, not sure where to turn now. From what I could gather from other posts, that data is stored temporarily. But, I can't seem to set a custom, non-temporary location for the data. So, now I'm populating a datastore every time I reboot, which seems ridiculous.

*** Edit ***

I've tried the following, which seems like it tries to launch the app, and creates a `datastore.db` file at the correct location:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path ~/go_apps/my_app/data/datastore.db  ~/go_apps/my_app/dispatch.yaml ~/go_apps/my_app/backend/app.yaml ~/go_apps/my_app/frontend/app.yaml
```

However, I'm getting a weird error now:

```
/var/folders/04/3hxnpxc15wj2k4v40lkdncd00000gn/T/tmpkcQYnFappengine-go-bin/backend.go:13: can't find import: "github.com/gorilla/mux"
```

Does Go build to that folder temporarily? That import is definitely available, and always builds fine calling `goapp serve`.

Here is what my imports look like on `backend.go`

```
import (
    //standard library
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "log"

    //third party
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/securecookie"
    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"

    //my imports
    "github.com/section14/go_polymer_comm_pkg/controller"
)
```

Comment: How do you stop your local appengine server? Do you explicitly stop it at all (before the restart)?

Comment: I explicitly stop it with `Control + C`. I'm getting the `Apply all pending transactions and saving the datastore` message.

Comment: The datastore is being saved to the same location every time, and it's definitely being deleted on system shutdown (the data persists rebooting the goapp server). My only goal is to change the datastore location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it up and running by adding both `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` environment variables to my .bash_profile. In total, these three paths (first path was already set) are needed for it to run:

```
# Add Google AppEngine path
export PATH=/Users/anthony/go_appengine:$PATH

# GOPATH
export GOPATH=/Users/anthony/go_appengine/gopath
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH

# GOROOT
export GOROOT=/Users/anthony/go_appengine/goroot
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT
```

This command is called from inside the project folder (mine resides outside of the appengine folder) for it to launch:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path data/datastore.db  dispatch.yaml backend/app.yaml frontend/app.yaml
```

Notice that the `.yaml` files are still there. It builds fine with them, and probably builds fine without them if you don't need a `dispatch.yaml` file.

**Thanks @icza for the direction. Wanted to organize the steps in a post for easier reading.**

Comment: You might want to mark your question as answered since you seem to have figured this out :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the name of the *file* to be used as the persisted datastore, *not* a folder.

And next provide the *folder* of your app (which contains `app.yaml`). Don't mix the 2. So it should be something like:

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=~/my_app/my_app.db ~/go_apps/my_app
```

Details can be found here:

[The Go Development Server / Using the Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/devserver?hl=en##Go_Using_the_Datastore)

**Notes:**

The default datastore file is in the temp folder, and your OS-X most likely clears that on system restart, that's why it is not preserved for you. On the other hand Windows 7 for example does not clear the temp folder on system restarts.

Comment: I've tried this already. Look at my post after *Edit*. I specify the datastore, but it complains about not finding my `github.com/gorilla/mux` package. In fact, if I start commenting out my imports, it can't find any of them. They are all located in `go_appengine/gopath/src`, which is where they should be. Just tried to build on Windows 7 with `dev_appserver.py`, and I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: `goapp serve` builds everything just fine, but there aren't any flags to specify the datastore location. Somehow `dev_appserver.py` can't find packages in `gopath/src`. Which is puzzling since goapp is just a wrapper around it.

Comment: @anthony Your edit shows that you provided the db file and the `.yaml` _files_, not the db file and the app _folder_. Please try that.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, I tried it by specifying the folder only, and I'm getting the same result: `/var/folders/04/3hxnpxc15wj2k4v40lkdncd00000gn/T/tmpkcQYnFappengine-go-bin/backend.go:13: can't find import: "github.com/gorilla/mux"` I appended the first post to show my imports. It doesn't crash until it gets past all the standard library imports (which it finds apparently).

Comment: Also, I tried to build the `frontend` by itself, and it builds just fine. Even if I leave `app.yaml` in the path. Still builds. So, it seems to me that my imports are the issue for some reason. Not sure where I'm supposed to move them though.

Comment: @anthony `goapp` sets the `GOROOT` and `GOPATH` environment variables. You should do that to point them into folders inside your SDK's `gopath` and `goroot` folders if you don't use `goapp`.